# gpg --receive-keys times out but Wireshark confirms the http response is received

Tags: proxy, apt, gpg

I'm using a virtual machine running Ubuntu 14.04, trying to use apt-keys to add keys for nginx.

Most of this is automatic via puppet but I'm going through the process manually to find where the fault lies.

The machine is behind a corporate proxy so all traffic is routed through cntlm, this works fine and has given me few issues so far.

The command which fails is along the lines of:

`gpg --debug-all -v --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 573BFD6B3D8FBC641079A6ABABF5BD827BD9BF62`

Which results in:

`gpg: requesting key 7BD9... from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver recieve failed: keyserver error`

Using Wireshark I can see the actual HTTP request done for this is

`http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80/pks/lookup?op=get&options=mr&search=0x573BFD6B3D8FBC641079A6ABABF5BD827BD9BF62`

Using a wget for the same url downloads the key as required instantly (no timeout/fault)

Looking at the wireshark logs the request and responses look exactly the same, there's an outgoing HTTP GET and an incoming 200 OK inn both cases, each time this is post proxy.

I am unsure how to dig deeper into the issue and would appreciate a nudge in the right direction to track this down!

Comment: Do you run wireshark on this virtual machine?

Comment: No, wireshark was running on the host machine watching the VM network interface

Comment: Can you run the wireshard also in the vm (preferably both, the same time)? I had networking trouble (unable to reach some hosts in local network) at some point with official vmware tools, had to switch to open vm tools.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I can try, will update when I get that working